# Firebase login with google popup taking too long to load

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

> Here is a preview of what is happening

[image]

The login with google popup is taking too long to load (>2s)
This is causing a bounce rate problem for our site.

Notice that the popup stays on the url `about: blank` for quite some time.

Here are some tech specs
This test is run on a 100mbps fiber connection with <9ms ping
Site is powered by angular
Browser is chrome

Firebase Imports:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

Code used to trigger the popup:

```
declare var firebase: any;

this.googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
this.googleProvider.addScope('email');
this.googleProvider.addScope('profile');

loginWithGoogle() {
    const that = this;
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(this.googleProvider).then(function (result) {
      const GoogleToken = result.credential.accessToken;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      const email = error.email;
      const credential = error.credential;
    });
  }
```

The remainder of the login process is going smoothly.
Can someone suggest any way we can speed this up ? 
Perhaps by preloading the google and facebook login pages before clicking the login button ?

Comment: Also, we are using firebase hosting to host the site in production.

Comment: The code looks fine, so it is unlikely that is the cause of the slowness you experience. In fact, I don't know of any way that you can control this performance in the code of your app. It might be best to post a bug to the [open-source SDK's repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk), although I'd also recommend there that you do a thorough investigation into *what* the SDK is doing in the time that you consider too long.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do i probe into what the sdk is doing ?

Comment: Trying with native google login and later connecting with firebase is much faster.

Comment: Interesting. If you can show the code for how to implement that, it'd make a good answer for others trying to improve things.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm also experiencing this exact issue. Also on 100mbps internet. The browser popup sits on a white window for a few seconds before showing a login url. Does Firebase have an internal ticket regarding this issue or any updates on it?

Answer (score 3):

@FrankvanPuffelen
This is what we did to speed up,

added native google signin imports in index.html

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
```

then in login component,

```
declare var gapi: any;


ngOnInit() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
      gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: "enter-client-id-here"
      });
    });
  }


loginWithGoogle() {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(googleUser => {
      const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function (error) {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        const email = error.email;
        const errorCred = error.credential;
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

**This is a workaround but still doesn't solve the original problem.**

Firebase being a product by google itself is expected to have these types of problems figured.